# Haskell - how to extract data types and function definitions from a text file?

Tags: file, haskell, types

I am stuck with an assignment I have to do for my own haskell project.
I have a .txt file, the structure of which looks like this:

```
types{
type1
type2
}

type1{
sub11
sub12
}

type2{
sub21
sub22
}

generate{
type1->type2
type2->type1
}
```

Now, I need to take the strings before each "{" and make them to a Data Type.
So, in this case :

```
 Data Types = Type1 | Type2
 Data Type1 = Sub11 | Sub12
 Data Type2 = Sub21 | Sub22
```

Between the last pair of brackets "{}"  are defined the functions like this:

```
 blob::Type1 -> Type2 -> String
 bar :: Type2 -> Type1 -> String
```

The blob and bar  functions must take all possible subtypes of Type1 and Type2 and build the cartesian product.
So, in this case the result of blob would be:(sub11,sub21),(sub11,sub22),(sub12,sub21),(sub12,sub22)

I know how to read a file in haskell with the readFile function which returns the file content as a string. What I do not know is how to parse the text from the text file and define the types and functions dinamically.

Comment: So what is your question? Do you need a recommendation on what parser library to use? That's the sort of question generally answerable by google and something stackoverflow discourages. Do you need help with a particular parsing technique? If so, please include the details in your question. As for dynamically defining types, that's not something that Haskell does. There are ways to describing generic types, but you end up with a value representing what the type would be if it were compiled, not a type itself. Your best bet would probably be to generate a Haskell file that is then compiled.

Comment: I just do not know how to start...I was thinking about using some shell script at first and generate the haskell file using the shell.

Comment: If you want to solve this problem with Haskell I would recommend starting with the parsec library.  It's a bit different for parsing text than what you're probably used to, but there's a lot of tutorials out there for how to use it, and it's really quite easy to use once you learn a few basics.  After that you can pretty simply produce your desired output.  Just follow the program flow "Get Input -> Parse Input to Internal Representation -> Manipulate Internal Representation -> Generate Output -> Save Output To Disk".  That way only the first and last steps should need IO.

Comment: Can you provide some links to good tutorials?

Comment: I'd start with the website: https://github.com/aslatter/parsec.

Comment: Do you actually find my idea to make a shell script better ? I don't really have much experience with haskell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133038/discussion-between-bheklilr-and-teo).